# Issue running Cosine Similarity on 50k records

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, cosine-similarity

I am using spark 1.6 cosine similarity algorithm in spark mllib.

Input: 50k documents' text with ids in a dataframe.

Processing :

- Tokenized the texts
- Removed stop words
- Generated vectors(size=300) using word2Vec
- Generated RowMatrix
- Transposed it
- Used columnSimilarities method with threshold 0.1.(Also tired higher 
  values)

Output is nxn matrix.

I am using this spark submit

spark-submit --master yarn --conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=256m" --num-executors 60 --driver-memory 10G --executor-memory 15G --executor-cores 5 --conf "spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true" --conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048" noname.jar xyzclass

I am also doing 400 partitions. 
But I am getting out of memory issues. I have tired different combinations for partitions and number of executors but failed to run it successfully. However I am able to run it successfully for 7k records with vector size 50 in less than 7mins. Any suggestions how I can make it run on 50K records?